# Does an eslint rule exist that complains if useEffect only has a return statement?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I just stumbled on some code at my company where a `useEffect` only had code in the `return` statement:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return doSomethingUseful()
}, [])
```

We discussed this and it was clearly a mistake and I can't think of a use case where this structure would be useful.
This got me wondering if there exists an eslint rule that would complain about this.

I've never written any custom rules of my own, so I haven't tried that path yet.

Comment: That can use to  do something when the component get unmount ( because the dependency array is empty ). Kind of similar to `componentWillUnmount` in React class component, or `OnDestroy` in Angular or `Destructor` in C++

Comment: @Dilshan Thanks. That is definitely true, but I'd still like to have eslint complain so that it would be *intentional* that something only happens on unmount